# Jenkins - how do I copy (clone) a pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to make a copy of one of my current pipelines - and create other ones, I,e, I am trying to do a template.

How can I do this in Jenkins?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a template, take a look at JTE - jenkins templating engine plugin.